# How to put full-screen image in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, fullscreen

I would like to know if there is a way to "hide" the Mac Desktop, and show something like a loading screen, while an operation is in progress, and then remove it.

Comment: Only while an operation is in progress? Why not just show a progress bar in the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [NSImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object, and fullscreen it by sending it [enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW5)